# How to access a switch in a menu using ViewBinding?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout

How to access a switch in a menu using ViewBinding ?

menu/drawer_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"

    >

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_read"
            android:title="@string/read"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_read"
        />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_write"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_write"
            android:title="@string/write"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_theme"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_theme"
            android:title="Dark Theme"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/theme_switch"
            />

    </group>


    <item android:title="@string/about">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_source_code"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_source_code"
                android:title="@string/source_code"/>

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

theme_switch.xml:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toggleSwitch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

activity_home.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

These are my layout files.

In brief, I've created a DrawerLayout inside which I've implemented my menu using NavigationView. One of the menu item is a switch and I want to add a `.setOnCheckedChangeListener` to this switch.

I've tried accessing the switch like this inside the `onCreate()` function of my activity:

```
 val switch = binding.navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_theme) as SwitchCompat
        switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked -> 
            
        }
```

However, it is throwing an exception that MenuItem cannot be cast into a SwitchCompat.

I don't see any otherway to access this switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a switch on your item, use actionViewClass to define the component.
And if a not mistaken you can remove `app:actionLayout="@layout/theme_switch"`

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat"
```